# IOS FindObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock -> setNeedsDisplay

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm running a Parse program which grabs the data and creates objects from it using 'findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock'. Once that is complete I update self and then call '[self.tableView setNeedsDisplay]', but nothing changes on my display and no new items are shown. Am I doing something wrong? and how do I fix it?

```
-(void)pullDown{
NSLog(@"Began PullDown");
NSMutableArray *bugs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];

//NSMutableArray *bugs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
NSLog(@"Journal POSTS");
PFQuery *queryJournal = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[queryJournal whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
NSLog(@"WHEN ARE YOU CALLED?");
[queryJournal findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *posts, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        //NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %@ Posts.", posts);
        // Do something with the found objects

        for (PFObject *object in posts) {
            int rating = object[@"Rating"];
            NSLog(@"RATING object: %@; int: %i", object[@"Rating"], rating);
            MSJournalerDoc *post = [[MSJournalerDoc alloc] initWithTitle:object[@"Title"] rating:rating thumbImage:object[@"imageFile"] fullImage:object[@"imageFile"]];
            [bugs addObject:post];
        }
        NSLog(@"HELL YA");
        NSLog(@"THE LIST: %@", bugs);
        self.bugs = bugs;
        NSLog(@"END OF LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOPS %lu", bugs.count);
        [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];
        NSLog(@"MOAR");
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    } 
}];
}




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        NSLog(@"CURRENT USER");
        [self pullDown];
        NSLog(@"POST CURRENT USER");
    }
    else{
        [self createUser];
        [self createBug];
    }


self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

//Change the Title
self.title = @"Posts";

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                          target:self action:@selector(addTapped:)];

NSLog(@"Finished ViewDidLoad");
}
```

Comment: You should use reloadData, not setNeedsDisplay to reload your table view with new data.

Comment: caused an 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFFile size]: unrecognized selector error

Comment: It's causing that error now because it's actually tying to reload the table, but you have another error somewhere in your code. I don't see any code in your question that uses PFFile

Comment: I think `MSJournalerDoc` wants to get `UIImage` objects from its thumbImage and fullImage arguments, but you are sending `PFFile` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of different issues.

First, calling `setNeedsDisplay` on a view causes it to be redrawn, but this isn't enough for a table view because none of its data has been updated. Instead, you need to call `reloadData` which will update the data and trigger a redraw automatically.

Secondly, you are trying to use images returned by parse, but parse never returns images (at least not directly). So, accessing `object[@"imageFile"]` is returning you a `PFFile`, not a `UIImage`. You need to call `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:` to get the image data before you can use it.

Comment: And, any operations on views, such as `setNeedsDisplay` and `reloadData` should be called on the main thread.